# Admin.UserCanEditFieldPermissions error while deploying using Bamboo

Tags: deployment, mdapi, mdapideploy

Error: "profileName", line 0: Error Admin.userCanEditFieldPermissions

Having trouble finding information about the above error when deploying Profiles using Bamboo. The deployment in question contains changes to fieldPermissions nodes, mostly granting readable or editable to existing fields.

Perhaps my Google Foo is weak with this particular issue... Anyone seen this and have a remedy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By any chance, this string is present in profile - userCanEditFieldPermissions. For the field visiblity all `<fieldPermissions>` tag shall present

Comment: Or are you trying to modify the standard profiles?